# Module Cython not found when installing Kivy 1.10.0

Tags: python, pip, kivy

I used pip to install Kivy 1.10.0 (Yes! I need this version, no more, no less). But when I run `pip install kivy==1.10.0`, I got this:

```
C:\Users\FlopffyGrape> pip install kivy==1.10.0

Collecting kivy==1.10.0
  Using cached Kivy-1.10.0.tar.gz (24.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\FlopffyGrape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\FlopffyGrape\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iiwz5ycz\\kivy_349a20b557a341848792819dc6f37ede\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\FlopffyGrape\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iiwz5ycz\\kivy_349a20b557a341848792819dc6f37ede\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\FlopffyGrape\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fyg82ilx'
       cwd: C:\Users\FlopffyGrape\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iiwz5ycz\kivy_349a20b557a341848792819dc6f37ede\
  Complete output (14 lines):
  C:\Users\FlopffyGrape\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iiwz5ycz\kivy_349a20b557a341848792819dc6f37ede\setup.py:69: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
    MIN_CYTHON_VERSION = LooseVersion(MIN_CYTHON_STRING)
  C:\Users\FlopffyGrape\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iiwz5ycz\kivy_349a20b557a341848792819dc6f37ede\setup.py:71: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
    MAX_CYTHON_VERSION = LooseVersion(MAX_CYTHON_STRING)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\FlopffyGrape\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iiwz5ycz\kivy_349a20b557a341848792819dc6f37ede\setup.py", line 219, in <module>
      from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
  Using distutils

  Cython is missing, it's required for compiling kivy !


  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/49/5c22589099f9b7fd106502ee6634a6675e634d7553fede141a7606e6a92d/Kivy-1.10.0.tar.gz#sha256=28c180fd5e4538858f0d2b3dde53c123d3a898d3ac7fba512bf3b83d0dfc248d (from https://pypi.org/simple/kivy/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy==1.10.0 (from versions: 1.0.1a0, 1.0.2a0, 1.0.3a0, 1.0.4b0, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0rc4, 2.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy==1.10.0
```

But Cython is already installed (The version is 0.29.26).
How can I solve this? (I'm using Window 10 and Python 3.9.1)

Comment: If Cython is really installed for the same Python version (so `pip show cython` finds it), then try `pip install kivy==1.10.0 --no-build-isolation`

Answer (score 1):

you should reinstall cython (`pip install cython`).